# QGIS Python Plugin Error When Executing Dissolve with Optional Multipart to Singlepart Conversion

Tags: qgis-plugins

I've been developing a QGIS plugin in Python that allows users to perform a dissolve operation on a selected vector layer and optionally convert it from multipart to singlepart. The plugin works as expected when performing the dissolve operation alone. However, when the option to convert the dissolved layer to singlepart is enabled, I encounter the following error:

> An error occurred during processing: QgsVectorLayer(): argument 1 has >unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'

The plugin allows users to select a vector layer from the loaded layers, choose an attribute field for the dissolve operation, and specify an output file location and name. The output can be saved as a Shapefile. The dissolve operation is executed using QGIS's processing framework, specifically the native:dissolve algorithm. If the user opts to convert the output to singlepart, the native:multiparttosingleparts algorithm is intended to be used.

The issue arises specifically when attempting to execute the multipart to singlepart conversion after the dissolve operation. The plugin works perfectly for the dissolve operation if the multipart to singlepart option is not selected by the user.

Here is a simplified version of the code responsible for executing the processing operations:

```py
def processLayer(self): 
    layer = self.dlg.cbVectorLayers.currentData() 
    attributeField = self.dlg.cbAttributeFields.currentText() 
    output_file = self.dlg.lineEditOutputPath.text()

    parameters_dissolve = {
        'INPUT': layer,
        'FIELD': [attributeField],
        'OUTPUT': output_file
    }

    feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

    try:
        result_dissolve = processing.run("native:dissolve", parameters_dissolve, feedback=feedback)
        if self.dlg.chkMultipartToSinglepart.isChecked():
            parameters_singlepart = {
                'INPUT': result_dissolve['OUTPUT'],
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
            }
            result_singlepart = processing.run("native:multiparttosingleparts", parameters_singlepart, feedback=feedback)
            layer_output = QgsVectorLayer(result_singlepart['OUTPUT'], "Processed Layer", "ogr")
        else:
            layer_output = QgsVectorLayer(result_dissolve['OUTPUT'], "Processed Layer", "ogr")

        if layer_output.isValid():
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer_output)
        else:
            raise Exception("Failed to load the resulting layer.")
    except Exception as e:
        QMessageBox.warning(None, "Processing error", f"An error occurred during processing: {str(e)}")
```

I have confirmed that the dissolve operation works correctly on its own, and the plugin successfully generates and loads the dissolved layer into QGIS. The error only occurs when I attempt to add the optional multipart to singlepart conversion step.

What might be causing this error and how do I resolve it, so that the plugin can correctly perform both operations as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result_singlepart['OUTPUT']` is already a `QgsVectorLayer` object, hence the error when you try to pass it to a `QgsVectorLayer` constructor in the line:

```py
QgsVectorLayer(result_singlepart['OUTPUT'], "Processed Layer", "ogr")
```

You can change

```py
result_singlepart = processing.run("native:multiparttosingleparts", parameters_singlepart, feedback=feedback)
layer_output = QgsVectorLayer(result_singlepart['OUTPUT'], "Processed Layer", "ogr")
```

to

```py
result_singlepart = processing.run("native:multiparttosingleparts", parameters_singlepart, feedback=feedback)
layer_output = result_singlepart['OUTPUT']
layer_output.setName("Processed Layer")
```